# How to evaluate the determinant of this $n \times n$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Find the following [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant):  $$\begin{vmatrix} 0 &1&0&0 &\cdots& 0\\  0 &0&1&0 &\cdots& 0\\  0 &0&0&1 &\cdots& 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots &\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0 &\cdots&1\\1&0&0&0 &\cdots&0\end{vmatrix}_{n \times n}$$

**Attempt**:
I switched $1^{st}$ row with the last one, then second with the last, and so on till the $(n-1)^{th}$ row with the $n^{th}$ (last) row and there I had all $1$'s in the diagonal so I came up with the answer $1$.

Am I correct? Can anyone solve this exercise please?

Comment: Yes. Zero. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: how? can you explain please

Comment: @copper.hat I don't think so. Note that the bottom left corner is a $1$.

Comment: Hint: switch columns (or rows) in order to change the matrix into $I$. Every switch changes the sign.

Comment: Well, zero plus or minus one.

Comment: Have you tried any simple examples to see if there is a pattern? Have you tried anything at all? Do you expect people to click on your link to look at your problem and them explain it to you without any context or obvious effort? This is sheer & utter laziness.

Comment: It is $(-1)^{n-1}.$

Comment: Expand along $C_1$

Comment: copper.hat Yes I've tried, I ended with the result 1 but I don't know if it's right..

Comment: The answer is $-1$ for $n=2$, so more analysis is needed.

Comment: Can you show us your working out so far maybe? That would allow us to more effectively help you I think, since we would have a better idea of where you had troubles.

Comment: I switched 1st row with the last one, then second with the last, and so on 'till the (n-1)th row with the n-th (last) row and there I had all 1's in the diagonal so I came up with the answer 1

Comment: Switching rows multiplies the determinant by $-1$. Did you take that into account?

Comment: No, I didn't know that..

Comment: Consider the determinant for $n=2$,$$\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{vmatrix}=-1$$When you switch $R_1$ and $R_2$, the determinant is$$\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{vmatrix}=|I_2|=1$$which is $-1$ times the original determinant. In your method, you ended up switching the rows $n-1$ times, so that$$(-1)^{n-1}\Delta=1\implies\Delta=(-1)^{n-1}$$I suggest you to expand the determinant along the first column, which will avoid all the switching to yield the answer.

Comment: Also, welcome to the website. Your original question did not meet the quality criteria here since you didn't provide any context: information about what you've tried to solve the question, where you found it, why is it relevant, etc.. Failing to provide context may result in downvotes/closure. Additionally, it is not considered good practice to post links to images of questions, since the links may expire with time. Refer [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic guide on Mathjax to be able to format your Math equations.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: row exchanges change the value of the determinant by a factor of $-1$, and the determinant of the identity is $1$. How do you make your matrix the identity by exchanging rows?

Comment: i dont know....

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding matrix is the companion matrix for the polynomial $$f(x)=x^n-1$$ So the characteristic polynomial for this matrix is $f(x)$. So determinant is same as product of all $n$ th root of unity, which is $(-1)^{n+1}$

Answer (score -1):

Expand along the first column. $\Delta=(-1)^{n+1}|I_{n-1}|=(-1)^{n+1}$, where $I_{n-1}$ is the identity matrix of order $n-1$.